# Do the primary Islamic sources mention the Seven Laws of Noah?

Tags: covenant

While not explicitly mentioned in the Bible, the Jewish oral history refers to the [Seven Laws of Noah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahide_laws) as binding on all mankind as part of the Covenant of the Rainbow.

While it is known that all prophets preached the same fundamental message of Islam, is there mention of these particular laws, as per this particular Covenant, in the primary sources?

Comment: You can ask ME:)

Comment: tell us what are these laws then we might answer

Comment: @talal they are described in the provided wikipedia link, summarized thus: Prohibition of Idolatry, Prohibition of Murder, Prohibition of Theft, Prohibition of Sexual immorality, Prohibition of Blasphemy, Prohibition of eating flesh taken from an animal while it is still alive, Establishment of courts of law.

Comment: I never about seven laws, but absolutely it's mentioned in quran that Allah revealed to Noah and advised him.

Answer (score 1):

In islam these prohibition things are called *Kaba'ir* (big sins), they include:

polytheism, sorcery, murder, usury, vilification, theft, perjury, illegal sexual intercourse and a few other sins.

There is no clear connection between them and Noah.

Concerning the number, the *Ahadith* mention different numbers for example:

[3](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/165) or [3](http://sunnah.com/nasai/37/44)

[4](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/166) or [4](http://sunnah.com/nasai/45/164) or [4](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/53)

[6](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/11)

[7](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/86/80)

In Surat Al-'An`ām you can find Ten Commandments:

[151](http://quran.com/6/151) and [152](http://quran.com/6/152) and [153](http://quran.com/6/153)